# Use HTML5 Tidy only for parts of HTML

Tags: html, vim, tidy

I would like to use HTML5 Tidy as `equalprg` (`=`) filter program in Vim. Is it possible to run `tidy` only on parts of HTML files?

Example:

```
$ echo '<br/>' | tidy $options
<br>
```

Default is that Tidy wraps `DOCTYPE`, `html`, `body` around the `<br>` tag...

Edit: I don't want to use the `input-xml` option because I don't have XML but HTML5.

Comment: Thank you for linking to the other question. But I think that does not work in this case. When I set the `input-xml` option the input is treated as XML and not as HTML5. But I have HTML5.

Comment: Answer: No, apperently it is not possible to run HTML5 Tidy  version 5 only on parts of *HTML* files.